# MYSQL table search-filtering

Tags: mysql, sql, database, subquery

I have a table `student` with a column `dte_date` (date) having values (2019-01-01,2019-02-01,2019-03-01..etc)

Conditions:

1. No repeated values in the column `dte_date`.
2. But there is a chance of missing values in `dte_date`(example miss 2019-02-01).
3. The day of the date field should be 01.

I want a query to check whether any month date is missing from this table.

Comment: I want a query to check any month date is missing in this table

Comment: You only needs to know there are missing dates with output Yes/No? Or also required the list of dates that are missing? Start and End dates are input?

Comment: What is the structure of your table ? Is the Dte_Date a key of it ? or is it a part of a multi column key ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use aggregating and `having`:

```
select student_id
from t
group by student_id
having max(dte_date) <> min(dte_date) + interval count(*) - 1 month;
```

Note that this assumes that you don't have duplicates in the table -- although that could be handled with `count(distinct)`.